# Standard pin out for 38KHz IR receiver to 3.5mm jack lead?

Tags: infrared, receiver

Is there a (rough) 'standard' for IR receiver 3.5mm jacks?
I wish to use one of the many IR receiver to 3.5mm jack leads Ive seen for sale, however none mention the pin out. I'm sure all combinations are used somewhere, however there appears to be some kind of standard, as many buyer comments mention 'it works great with their XXX...'. I'm leaning towards Outer=GND, ring=+V, tip=DATA if I had to guess, though would rather not. Note (for moderators) Im not asking for opinion, but asking if a standard exists and if so what is it.

Comment: Why would you want such a thing on a 3.5mm jack?  And for what purpose?  If it's supposed to plug into an _audio_ port it needs to be more than just an IR receiver.  Questions about _products_ are not on topic here; this site is only for design questions and related things supported by design-level technical detail in the question itself.  If you had documentation of a specific technical requirement there might be the possibility of an on-topic question, but it seems you do not.

Comment: @ChrisStratton TRS jacks for infrared receivers are common on things like cable boxes or AV input switches that might be located somewhere they can't easily see the remote. This is still an off-topic question, though.

Comment: choose an arrangement that prevents any possible shorting on Vcc to gnd when a sensor is plugged in ... also think of future expansion ... for instance, the detection of a sensor connection ... a TRRS jack may be more appropriate

Comment: Thanks - shorting was my concern - maybe finding a safe way to test is the answer. Would be nice to know before a purchase mind. With so many for sale I'm assuming they must be fairly generic. And for so cheap would be great for projects.

Comment: Unless you can state specifically what you need, assistance is not available here.  You'll have to try the manufacturer, a web search on the target product, or seek out a user community for that product.

Answer (score 1):

One of the original manufacturers of these sort of products is Keene Electronics. Their datasheet ([here](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0021/6426/0934/files/Keene_IR_Receiver_and_Emitters_Connections.pdf?6678134990961341812)) shows the tip as signal out, ring as +5V supply and sleeve as ground, which doesn't seem particularly intuitive.

The datasheet also includes some information regarding systems used by alternative manufacturers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know of any standard but logically I would expect the tip to be +5 followed by signal out and the barrel being ground.

You could certainly measure that on your receiver box.